# Nativescript : error: exportArchive: objc-metadata-generator has conflicting provisioning settings

Tags: ios, nativescript

I have a problem with my app. When I run `tns run ios` I got this error and I can't solve it in a proper way. I search on the internet and I have tried many solutions but still doesn't work.

`tns run ios`

```
error: exportArchive: objc-metadata-generator has conflicting provisioning settings.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=8 "objc-metadata-generator has conflicting provisioning settings." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=objc-metadata-generator has conflicting provisioning settings., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=objc-metadata-generator is automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Developer has been manually specified. Remove the "signingCertificate" entry from your Export Options property list, or switch to manual signing by setting "signingStyle" to "Manual.}
** EXPORT FAILED **

Unable to apply changes on device: 011e78a2e571258b3ccb12826abcc932103393df. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 70.
```

`tns info
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information      │
│ nativescript     │ 3.4.4           │ 5.0.0          │ Update available │
│ tns-core-modules │ 3.4.1           │ 5.0.2          │ Update available │
│ tns-android      │ 3.4.2           │ 5.0.0          │ Update available │
│ tns-ios          │ 3.4.1           │ 5.0.0          │ Update available │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────┘`

Comment: Are you trying to run on device? If Yes, try passing the `--provision Your_Provisional_Profile_Id]`